# As per Ocean Girl can we talk under water?

Tags: ocean-girl

In Series 3, Episode 1 and Episode 18 respectively, divers from ORCA & UBRI are talking underwater. Can any one explain to me how they talk when their mouths are attached with the mouthpiece of the oxygen tank (even if they have some kind of phones to talk).

[image]

Per this image I'm confused how this UBRI Guy move his lips to talk:

[image]

Comment: so that's mean we are fooled by Ocean Girl Makers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

In Season 3, Episode 18, the spoken communication among UBRI members appears to be via some form of wireless device (most likely [ultrasonic](http://www.gizmag.com/casio-logosease-scuba-communications/24998/), or ultrasonic-to-surface-to-radio).

> Kellar:   Still hasn’t noticed us.
>
> Hellegren: Definitely less alert than
> the girls. But we must be quick.
>
> Kellar:    What’s your position?
>
> UBRI: 20 metres from target.
>
> Hellegren:    Now.
>
> Kellar:    Full speed.
>
> Kellar:   About to dive directly towards you.

Here the UBRI team leader underwater appears to be talking to the people abovewater through a wireless communication unit, with them relaying their instructions the same way.
Underwater communication between UBRI commandos in this episode is gestural, or perhaps via a sign language.

In Season 3, Episode 1, the mechanism is similar. Notice how the dialogue sounds mechanical, like a radio. Also note how it cuts off sharply before and after Jason and his mother start speaking.

The receivers are probably inside the mouthpiece, much as in [real life](http://www.scuba.com/scuba-gear-124/029944/Ocean-Reef-Neptune-Space-G.divers-Full-Face-Mask-with-Diver-Communication-Unit.html).
That said, while this is obviously supposed to be the case in-universe, the **masks portrayed don't seem to be the sort that allow speech**.

That said, since this is science fiction, the devices could be something like [this](http://www.gizmag.com/casio-logosease-scuba-communications/24998/), which doesn't require a full-face mask.

Comment: Radio doesn't work underwater, either. For example, submarines need to rise to periscope depth to send messages.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - It could be something like [this](http://www.divelink.net/mnews.htm)

Comment: @JohnSensebe - You're right, water is too good a conductor. They're probably using something like [this.](http://www.rjeint.com/images/datasheetspdf82815/600-18011%208-15-2015%20SSB-2010.pdf)

Comment: That is technically not radio. ;-) A modicum of research suggests that wireless underwater communications use acoustic waves instead of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Look at my post.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - I'm a physicist: I actually do know what you're talking about. :)

Comment: As far as the masks go, maybe they are all trained ventriloquists, and can speak without moving their lips. So long as their tongues can noothe threely, they shouldn't hathe a kroglen.